# Probability of collision with truncated SHA-256 hash

Tags: math, hash, probability, sha, sha256

I have a database-driven web application where the primary keys of all data rows are obfuscated as follows: SHA256(content type + primary key + secret), truncated to the first 8 characters. The content type is a simple word, e.g. "post" or "message" and the secret is a 20-30 char ASCII constant. The result is stored in a separate indexed column for fast DB lookup.

How do I calculate the probability of a hash collision in this scenario? I am not a mathematician at all, but a friend claimed that due to the Birthday Paradox the collision probability would be ~1% for 10,000 rows with an 8-char truncation. Is there any truth to this claim?

Comment: Since SHA-256 produces a sequence of bytes, not all of which represent valid characters for output, you are probably encoding the output before truncation for display purposes - the encoding will influence your collision rate. If you are encoding in hexadecimal, which is fairly common, then 8 digits represent the first 32 bits of the hash. Encoding in base-64, though, would give 48 bits of the hash in 8 digits, and a corresponding increase in your collision space.

Answer (score 10):

Yes, there is a collision probability & it's probably somewhat too high. The exact probability depends on what "8 characters" means.

Does "8 characters" mean:

- A) You store 8 hex characters of the hash?  That would store 32 bits.
- B) You store 8 characters of BASE-64? That would store 48 bits.
- C) You store 8 bytes, encoded in some single-byte charset/ or hacked in some broken way into a character encoding?  That would store 56-64 bits, but if you don't do encoding right you'll encounter character conversion problems.
- D) You store 8 bytes, as bytes? That genuinely stores 64 bits of the hash.

Storing binary data as either A) hex or D) binary bytes, would be my preferred options. But I'd definitely recommend either reconsidering your "key obfuscation" scheme or significantly expanding the stored key-size to reduce the (currently excessive) probability of key collision.

From Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Probability_table

The birthday problem in this more generic sense applies to hash functions: the expected number of N-bit hashes that can be generated before getting a collision is not 2^N, but rather only 2^(N/2).

Since in the most conservative above understanding of your design (reading it as A, 8 chars of hex == 32 bits) your scheme would be expected to suffer collisions if it stored on the scale of ~64,000 rows. I would consider such an outcome unacceptable for all serious, or even toy, systems.

Transaction tables may have volumes, allowing growth for the business, from 1000 - 100,000 transactions/day (or more). Systems should be designed to function 100 years (36500 days), with a 10x growth factor built in, so..

For your keying mechanism to be genuinely robust & professionally useful, you would need to be able to scale it up to potentially handle ~36 billion (2^35) rows without collision. That would imply 70+ bits of hash.

The source-control system Git, for example, stores 160 bits of SHA-1 hash (40 chars of hex == 20 bytes or 160 bits). Collisions would not be expected to be probable with < less than 2^80 different file revisions stored.

---

A possibility better design might be, rather than hashing & pseudo-randomizing the key entirely & hoping (against hope) to avoid collisions, to prepend/ append/ fold-in 8-10 bits of a hash *into* the key.

This would generates a larger key, containing all the uniqueness of the original key plus 8-10 bits of verification.  Attempts to access keys would then be verified, and more than 3 invalid requests would be treated as an attempt to violate security by "probing" the keyspace & would trigger semi-permanent lockout.

The only major costs here, would be a modest reduction in the size of the available keyspace for a given int-size.  32-bit int to/from the browser would have 8-10 bits dedicated to security, thus leaving 22-24 for the actual key. So you'd use 64-bit ints where that was not sufficient.

Comment: The Wikipedia page no longer has a `#Cast as a collision problem` section, but there is [Wikipedia: Birthday_problem#Probability_table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem#Probability_table).